Issue migrating from Apache Camel 4.4 to 4.8 with route builders that contain rest and direct routes
Unable to get existing camel route builders that contain rest and direct camel routes to work properly.  Only the rest routes are registered and started, the direct routes are not registered.  If I remove the rest route, then the direct routes are registered and started.
Here is a sample test that uses a route builder class that contains the direct examples from the Camel Rest documentation.  The rest route is registered but the direct routes are not registered.  If I change the direct routes to seda routes, then all three routes are registered.  If I remove the rest route, then then two direct routes are registered.
import org.apache.camel.builder.RouteBuilder;
import org.apache.camel.test.junit5.CamelTestSupport;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.assertNotNull;

public class CamelRouteTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    @Test
    public void testContext() throws Exception {
        context.addRoutes(new TestRouteBuilder());
        context.start();
        assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("direct:hello"));
        assertNotNull(context.hasEndpoint("direct:bye"));
    }

    private static class TestRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

        @Override
        public void configure() {
            rest("/say")
                    .get("/hello").to("direct:hello")
                    .get("/bye").consumes("application/json").to("direct:bye")
                    .post("/bye").to("mock:update");

            from("direct:hello")
                    .transform().constant("Hello World");

            from("direct:bye")
                    .transform().constant("Bye World");
        }
    }
}


I think I found the answer thanks to a fellow college of mine.  If I set inline routes to false on the rest configuration for the context before adding routes, then everything works as expected.  Looks like this configured changed default values which I find very frustrating.
